# Select form table A where value in table B

Tags: mysql

Table A

```
id    name
1     name1
2     name2
3     name3
4     name4
```

Table B

```
id    userlist
1     1,2,3,4
```

What I do now is

```
SELECT `userlist` FROM `table B` WHERE `id` = 1
```

Then save the result and put into second query

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table A` WHERE `id` in ($userlist)
```

Just wondering if got better way. I try

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table A` WHERE `id` in (SELECT `userlist` FROM `table B` WHERE `table B`.`id` = 1)
```

But it only return 1 result.

EDIT*

DB structure can not be change since so many data inside. I just try to optimize the old code.

Comment: having comma separated values in a single field of a table is generally a bad idea. You should think about your data representation.

Comment: Normalize your DB, then you can use `IN` or `WHERE EXISTS`

Comment: See also [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: "*DB structure can not be change since so many data inside*" - why should the amount of data in the database prevent you from altering its structure?  Schema changes can be effected with database queries that perform all of the restructuring for you.

Comment: @eggyal O,ok. But I need ensure all the new insert data can match this new DB structure right before change the DB? If not, it can cause an error. For now, I just optimize bit by bit without doing major change since I'm not totally understand the whole architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT `name`
FROM `table A` INNER JOIN `table B` ON
     FIND_IN_SET(`table A`.`id`, `table B`.`userlist`)
WHERE `table B`.`id` = 1
```

but i would suggest you to normalize your tables.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to solve this is changing the table definition and using JOINs. For example

Table A

```
id    name    b_id
1     name1   1
2     name2   1
3     name3   1
4     name4   1
```

Table B

```
id    
1
```

To get names from table A that have B id 1 you would write:

```
select name from A join B on A.b_id = B.id where B.id = 1
```

Or, if you can't change Table A, define a new table to maintain the relationship A-B:

Table A

```
id    name
1     name1
2     name2
3     name3
4     name4
```

Table B

```
id    
1
```

Table A_B

```
a_id b_id
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
```

SQL to extract data:

```
select name from A join A_B on A.id = A_B.b_id where A_B.b_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Sorry to tell. The DB structure can't be change since im not one that create it. I just try to optimize it.

Comment: @MuhammadAzizol tell the derp who created the tables then to improve them. Or better, hit him with something heavy :) non-normalized tables are an evil better rooted out immediately, than dealing with later.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin I would like to. But he already left the company. Now all his work dump to me and I have to take the blame

Comment: @MuhammadAzizol where is the problem then? redo it, and do it right :)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin yeah, that was my plan. But for now i need to make it abit faster since the software already live.